# Abinito job status from backend

Tags: ab-initio

I want to find the Status of all the the plans that was run was it successful or not.

Example in oozie jobs
Ozzie jibs -ozzie url Status =success

Tried different air command to get the Status but none of them are giving expected results.

I want to get the Status of all the plans that was successful for making reports.